# How to automate Windows Run application using Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, automation

I need to open Run from my Ruby script and type the location of a file and click OK. I have seen some examples to open notepad and entering text using WIN32OLE but I am not sure how to open the Run command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, I think you can do:

```
`start location_of_my_file`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with any of the following commands in ruby

1) `exec`

2) using backtick or %x

3) `system`

Along with the name of the file you should also give the name of the program that should execute it.

Ex: If you want to open calculator then you can just do

```
exec 'calc' # or `calc` or %x(calc) or system 'calc'
```

Ex: If you want to open a text file in notepad  then :

```
exec 'notepad file_name.txt'
```

or

```
`notepad file_name.txt`
```

or

```
%x(notepad file_name.txt)
```

or

```
system 'notepad file_name.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that you can do it:

```
require 'win32ole'

def power
  wsh = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')
  if not wsh.AppActivate('powershell')
    wsh.Run('powershell')
    sleep(3)
    wsh.SendKeys('gwmi win32_bios{ENTER}')
    wsh.SendKeys('gwmi win32_processor{ENTER}')
    wsh.SendKeys('gwmi win32_volume{ENTER}')
    wsh.SendKeys('ls{ENTER}')
    wsh.SendKeys('ping 192.168.0.14{ENTER}')
    wsh.SendKeys('exit')
  end


end

power
```